# java -'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows 7

Tags: java, windows

jdk1.8.0_92 is installed in my Windows 7 and was able to set the path variable but didn't work, so I tried something but still keeps on giving me the same error. In my cmd it says this: javac is not recognized as an internal or external command

I have set JAVA_HOME and PATH variable.
path looks like this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files     
(x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS 
Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROO 
T%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)  
Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) 
Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management   
Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management  
Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program   
Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
```

JAVA_HOME looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
```

CLASSPATH looks like this:

```
.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib
```

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: are you able to run java -version? And did you open a new command line window after changing the env variable?

Comment: is the installation path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92` is correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In classpath, the correct way to set Java is 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;`

if your java is installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92` directory.

so instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib` in your classpath, add the one I posted above.

And one thing, after setting it, open a new command line to execute javac as it in not picked by currently opened window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin
```

The `javac` exe is a JDK program, and the file path you reffered to is a JRE program folder provided with the JDK

Comment: for me JAVA_HOME looks ok. In the Path he refer to the bin folder. %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: @Patrick As soon as i posted that edit, i looked at that and realized he had included the `\bin` in the path variable, so i removed the edit

Answer (score 0):

Your class path should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Once you install java in your machine, to set JAVA_HOME you should refer `bin` folder not lib folder.